# Est-ce que la construction « Au nombre de fois que » est correcte dans la phrase citée dans le corps de la question?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

C’est une tournure que je rencontre couramment à l’oral et je me demande si c’est du bon français ou non.

> Il n’y a pas de quoi! **Au nombre de fois que/où** ça m’arrive, je ne serais pas bien placé pour parler »

Quels seraient des exemples de manières plus élégantes de réécrire la phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À mon avis, qu'il soit fait usage de « que » ou de « où », la construction qui résulte  n'est pas du tout idiomatique, bien que l'on puisse comprendre ce que le locuteur voudrait expliquer. La préposition « à » doit être remplacée par un terme plus expressif.

- **Considérant** le nombre de fois **que**  ça m’arrive, je ne serais pas bien placé pour parler.
- **Au vu** du nombre de fois **que**  ça m’arrive, je ne serais pas bien placé pour parler.
- **En considération** du nombre de fois **que**  ça m’arrive, je ne serais pas bien placé pour parler. (*formel*)
- **Étant donné** le nombre de fois **que**  ça m’arrive, je ne serais pas bien placé pour parler.

Answer (score 0):

> ... Comme ça m'arrive souvent, je suis mal placé pour parler.
> ... [Vu](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/21855/la-grammaire/le-verbe/accord-du-participe-passe/sans-auxiliaire/emploi-prepositionnel-et-adjectival-du-participe-passe-sans-auxiliaire) que ça m'arrive souvent, je suis mal placé pour parler.
> ... Au nombre de fois où ça m’arrive, je suis mal placé pour parler. (Québec)

Le contexte est parfaitement anodin, le sociolecte est québécois et l'élégance consiste aussi à reconnaître l'usage ; par ailleurs on ne doit pas confondre l'élégance avec le baroque ni avec l'hypercorrection. On trouve la dernière tournure au Québec où elle y est naturelle ([1](https://plus.lapresse.ca/screens/268fad78-6ed4-4545-98f4-783389b3b0fd__7C___0.html), [2](https://ici.radio-canada.ca/sports/1828577/heure-verite-canadien-montreal-camp-entrainement-kaiden-guhle-poehling-harvey-pinard), [3](https://www.journaldequebec.com/2022/05/20/la-catastrophe-davoir-isole-les-vieilles-personnes)). D'habitude, on assimile le mot « fois » à une indication de temps (LBU14, § 725 a) et donc je préfère employer le relatif *où*.