# Comment s'analyse « au nombre de fois où X, Y » etc. ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Dans une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52355) on a déniché une tournure populaire probablement régionale (Québec) et peu étayée : « Au nombre de fois où [proposition X], [proposition Y] », par exemple :

> **Au nombre de fois où** le gouvernement s’est fait dire en commission
> parlementaire à quel point les services de santé à domicile étaient
> déficients, jamais je ne croirai que le peu qu’il y a puisse être
> retiré un jour. ([Louise Deschâtelets](https://www.journaldequebec.com/2022/05/20/la-catastrophe-davoir-isole-les-vieilles-personnes), Journal de Québec)

---

- Peut-on nommer la nature du lien qui unit les deux propositions et la
  fonction grammaticale du premier élément de la première proposition (« Au nombre de fois ») dans la phrase ?
- Peut-on dire s'il y a une différence quelconque avec « étant donné le
  nombre de fois... » et comment la préposition *à* réussirait à en être l'« équivalent » ?
- L'a-t-on déjà entendu à l'extérieur du Québec ?

Answer (score 1):

1. 

Il n'existe pas deux propositions, mais cinq.
« où le gouvernement s’est fait dire en commission parlementaire à quel point les services de santé à domicile étaient déficients »,

qui est bien une proposition,  fait partie du syntagme nominal

« Au nombre de fois où le gouvernement s’est fait dire en commission parlementaire à quel point les services de santé à domicile étaient déficients ».

« à quel point les services de santé à domicile étaient déficients » est une autre proposition, enchassée dans la proposition « où le gouvernement … »

« jamais je ne croirai » est la troisième proposition, une principale.

que le peu … puisse être retiré un jour » est la quatrième proposition, une conjonctive introduite par « que ».

Enfin « qu'il y a » est une relative enchassée dans la conjonctive.

En terme d'analyse de phrase complexe, La phrase toute entière n'est qu'une proposition principale dont le verbe est « croire ».

Il est utile de passer de la phrase en question à un type simplifié.

- Au nombre de fois, je ne le crois pas. — Je ne le crois pas, au nombre de fois.

Ce qui ressort de cette construction est, grossièrement, une idée de cause, mais elle n'est pas communiquée par une proposition ; elle est communiquée de façon non systématique par la sémantique ( « à », « nombre », « croire »).

- À cause du nombre de fois je ne le crois pas. (*grossièrement*)

2. 

C'est bien un équivalent  de « étant donné » ou mieux encore « à en juger par », locution tendant à devenir prépositionnelle qui contient « à », cependant  erroné du point de vue usage, et avec des nuances.
La préposition « à » « réussit » à en être l'équivalent, mais par le biais d'une distorsion, c'est à dire, à mon avis, d'une déformation de l'usage actuel. Pour comprendre, ce que le TLFi explique à son entrée pour « à » est capital.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0)) **I.** − À dans le syntagme verbal (à sert à construire un complément du verbe)
> **F.** − [***À* introduit un complément circonstanciel de manière, de matière, d'indice, de cause, de moyen, etc.**]
> **c)** ***À* introduit un compl. d'indice ou de cause**
> − **Le verbe de base est un verbe de perception ou d'entendement. Le compl. désigne un indice** :
> reconnaître qqn au pas.
> je vois ça à des tas de petits trucs
> découvrir le coupable à un indice
> il s'apercevait à d'imperceptibles affleurements que ...
> il peut se dépister à un symptôme commun à ...
> tu le sens à un léger fourmillement de tout ton dos
> mais au mouvement de ses bras, je pouvais croire que ...
> on devinait, aux rides profondes qui se creusaient dans son visage, que ...
> à l'accent méprisant qu'elles avaient, ...
> la fille entendait qu'elles mentaient
> et je surpris d'ailleurs, au ton employé par lui, qu'il ...
> à cette colère, Jean vit que ...
> il comprit, à la description, que ...
> il se demanda, à la seule lecture de la lettre, si ...

Le lien est donc précisément *l'indice* (oublier l'idée de cause utilisée plus haut).
Pour revenir à la question citée dans l'OP et la phrase douteuse,

> « Il n’y a pas de quoi! Au nombre de fois que/où ça m’arrive, je ne serais pas bien placé pour parler. »,

la locution verbale « être bien placé pour », n'est pas un verbe d'entendement, d'où l'impression d'un manque  total d'idiomaticité.

De même, « croire » n'est pas un verbe d'entendement ; il est par nature beaucoup plus proche d'un tel verbe, mais toujours pas assez caractéristique de ce type de verbe ; donc, à mon opinion,  la phrase prise comme exemple dans l'OP, elle non plus, n'est  pas acceptable.

3/ Il n'a été question ci-dessus que du français parlé en métropole, et la question sur l'usage au Québec me dépasse complètement.

Comment: Je dirais au contraire que _(ne pas) être bien placé pour_  (être ou non dans une situation favorable pour) avec le conditionnel se rapproche de _croire ne pas être_, voire comprendre, et ne permet pas de distinguer les deux ou de les exclure d'un emploi compatible avec celui que tu as identifié.

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle «¨Être bien placé » serait un verbe d'entendement ? «¨Être bien placé pour comprendre » serait « comprendre » ?

Comment: @CrissyFroth-Seapickle Quel est le « lien » alors ?

Comment: _Je ne pense pas être dans une position pour_ (te le reprocher, vu que ça m'arrive souvent aussi). C'était ça le sens de la phrase dans l'autre question. L'interlocuteur avait posé un geste, s'était excusé, puis on avait cette réponse...

Answer (score 1):

*Au nombre de fois où le gouvernement s’est fait dire en commission parlementaire à quel point les services de santé à domicile étaient déficients, jamais je ne croirai que le peu qu’il y a puisse être retiré un jour.*

This is perfect Hexagonal French.

The sentence is to be analyzed as follows :

- a PP (Prepositional Phrase) adjunct, sometimes called an *adverbial* in this case (since it is of the semantic type *predicate of events*), which scopes over the remaining of the sentence;

  - inside this PP adverbial, the NP (Noun Phrase) *nombre de fois* is completed by the **relative subordinate clause** *où... déficients*, introduced by the relative adverbial pronoun *où*;
  - inside the relative clause, an **interrogative subordinate clause** (which like all interrogative clauses, could also be considered as a free relative working as a Concealed Question) is introduced by *quel* : *à quel point... déficients*;
- the remaining of the **matrix clause**, *jamais je ne croirai que le peu qu’il y a puisse être retiré un jour*, whose main verb is *croirai*, contains **two subordinate clauses** embedded one inside the other:

  - *que le peu qu’il y a puisse être retiré un jour* is a **conjunctive clause**, object of *croirai*, introduced by the Complementizer (*conjonction de subordination* in French scholar grammar) *que* and whose verb is *puisse*;
  - the subject of the conjunctive clause, *le peu qu’il y a*, is a DP (Determiner Phrase); the complement of D is composed of a susbtantivized Adverb *peu* and a complement *qu'il y a*, which is a **relative clause** introduced by the accusative form of the relative pronoun, namely *que* (whose elided form is *qu'*).

So, **5 clauses**. (Or, since the phrase which the initial detached adjunct scopes over is a whole viable clause, we might count 6 clauses; traditionally though, the number of clauses equals the number of tensed verbs, and thus, detached adverbials do not increase the counter. -- But this is a controversial position to hold, since some sentences lack a verbal predicate to begin with : *Demain, concert !*).

---

Now about *au nombre de fois où*.

It does not express a cause, but a *criterion* which the locutor relies on to emit their judgment: 'judging by the number of times... then...'.

Simple example : *À ta tête, tu as dû rater ton examen !*

Note that *étant donné que* basically means *given the fact that*, so it is also used to introduce the data based on which a conclusion is made;  it thus tends to be a synonym of *puisque*. Contrary to *parce que*, which by default expresses an objective cause, *étant donné que* and *puisque*, for their part, insist on the subjective side of the rationale, on the reasoning and the supposed obviousness of the consequence it implies:

```
"Vas-y termine, [puisque/*parce que] tu as commencé !"
```

Side remark. -- As is the case for many semantic nuances in adjuncts, there is not necessarily an official term provided by the scholar grammar. As for generative studies, especially within frameworks that involve a strongly computational approach, they do not really need to make such semantic distinctions when analyzing the syntactic structure. However, in the TLF, as quoted by `LPH`, the expression *complément d'indice* is used.

Comment: *Matrix clause* c'est en quelque sorte une proposition principale. Seulement je rechigne à dire "principale", parce que le contenu des manuels et des discours des profs est affligeant d'incohérence, par ex. dans *je veux que tu viennes*, *je veux* serait la proposition principale, ce qui est aberrant puisqu'on vient d'amputer la proposition de son COD; et c'est encore pire avec une conjonctive sujet du type *Que tu viennes à ma fête me ferait plaisir.* C'est donc une proposition *matrice*, c'est-à-dire englobante (*embedding*).

Comment: @Crissy Je vois, c'est le Grevisse. Il sépare complètement les deux cas, traités dans deux paragraphes distincts, le seul point commun étant l'emploi de la préposition *à*.

Comment: réf: [LBU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpPET.png). Oui, mais l'un n'empêcherait pas l'autre et il dit _notamment_ et je me demande si l'emploi dans ma question peut aussi être hyperbolique indépendamment de son analyse grammaticale (différente, comme tu l'évoques), en plus d'être un équivalent potentiel d'un gérondif. J'essaie d'identifier une raison (supplémentaire) d'employer cette tournure plutôt qu'une autre, en plus de l'aspect subjectif/indice.

Comment: @Crissy. Non, dans ta question la tournure n'a absolument **rien** à voir avec l'emploi consécutif, je suis formel.